# Can't upgrade to SQL Server 2012 Express from SQL Server Express 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following version of SQL Server Express installed on my local machine:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (Intel X86) 
Sep 16 2010 20:09:22 
Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation
Express Edition on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (WOW64)
```

I'm trying to upgrade to SQL Server 2012 Express. I'm running on a 64 bit machine so I downloaded the SQLEXPRE_x86_ENU file from [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-sa/download/details.aspx?id=29062). I've been downloading 32 versions to run as the existing version was a 32 bit one. Originally the Engine was 2005 but I upgraded to 2008 and then 2008 service pack 2 (all 32bit)

However the upgrade fails. I end up with the following error:

```
Rule "Previous upgrade" failed. 

A previous upgrade that failed was detected. To retry the upgrade, remove the upgraded feature that failed, and then run the upgrade again.
```

I also ran a discovery report and this looked as follows:

[image]

Can anyone explain what the cause of this may be?

I should also add that I also tried upgrading to 2008 r2 express but that also failed for a similar reason.

Comment: Why would you download an x86 version for an x64 machine? Have you considered just installing a new instance and then using backup/restore to move your databases? I've never been too comfortable with in-place upgrades of Express Edition.

Comment: my starting point was a 2005 x86 engine so I figured I'd keep it consistent.  If I download the 64bit engine will I have to use it in a different version of Management Studio?

Comment: No, Management Studio doesn't have a 64-bit version - you don't need a different version to manage different engines. Just make sure Management Studio is >= the highest version you have to manage.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your previous install takes some errors.

[http://sqlblog.com/blogs/roman_rehak/archive/2010/10/28/issues-with-2008-to-r2-upgrade.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20170629012043/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/roman_rehak/archive/2010/10/28/issues-with-2008-to-r2-upgrade.aspx)